# Javascript Properties Overloading ala PHP?

Tags: javascript, overloading

I'm trying to find a way to to property overloading like it's done in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

i.e.

```
var myobj = function () {}
myobj.prototype.getProperty = function (propertyName) { console.log('Property Requested: ', propertyName); }

var otherObj = function () {};

myobj.hello; // Property Request: hello
otherObj.hello; // undefined
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible with some extended Javascript interpreters, but not universally.

Comment: It would help if you showed all the code. At the moment otherObj is a literal notation of an empty function.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing can only be done in ECMAscript 5 which is not supported in all browsers (e.g. IE).  Using `Object.defineProperty` you can create properties with accessor functions - so you could implement a property like `length` in arrays that varies, depending on the object state.

There's a good presentation from Doug Crockford about these features and with links to more detailed descriptions [here](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-1-properties-and-property-descriptors/).